# 3d projection from a perspective

Tags: 3d, lua, 2d

I am working on a library for an existing game, for this project, i want to do some 3d projection mapping, i do however have a few difficulties that makes the task harder.

I know quite a lot about the world, just not about the camera.

- I have the mouse screen position
- I have the mouse world position, captured at the same time as the screen position.
- I can get the Camera X,Y and Z in the gameworld.
- I can't get the FOV of the camera.

The first two i can get an at any time using functions.

From this i need to find the 2d screen position of an object which i only have the world coordinates of.

I have tried getting the distance from the camera to the object on the ground, and from that getting the cameras distance to the screen, then using the diagram from this article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

But the world is at an angle and the camera is slightly tilted. Meaning that the distance from the points i get, as well as the object itself is father away at the top of the monitor compared to the bottom.

To be noted is also that Z is ALWAYS up (on the monitor) there is no rotation of the camera.

I am sure this isn't a hard problem to solve, but i just can't keep all the information in my head.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is this question tagged as lua?

Comment: Because i am doing it in lua. and therefore i don't have access to all those fancy things in C++ and C.